# Gradle Main class could not be load or found

Tags: gradle

i'm new to gradle i always used maven but due to university i have to use gradle now.
When i use this build.gradle it cant load or find a main class:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'me.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


mainClassName = 'propa.Main'



dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.7.0-M1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox
    compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.19'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.16.1'

}
```

But when i just use another class without a package so f.e. just Test it works does someone know why and what i have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and to the Gradle community :)

Parts of your script appears to be for a very old version of Gradle. I am assuming you are using the newest release (6.4) or at a least relatively new one.

The main class definition belongs in an `application` block like this:

```
application {
    mainClassName = 'propa.Main'
}
```

This is documented in the [Gradle Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

Though not related to your question, you also have a conflict of JUnit libraries in that you are using both a legacy JUnit 4 library and a JUnit 5 (Jupiter) library. Also, be careful about using milestone releases (5.7.0-M1) unless you are prepared to struggle with potential bugs and incompatibilities.

I recommend Jupiter if nothing else matters. If you want to go with that, you also have to add a few things as documented in the [User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#using_junit5). For example, it could look like this:

```
dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter API for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'

    // Use JUnit Jupiter Engine for testing.
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform() // Only if you want to use Jupiter
}
```

Also notice that the modern way to declare dependencies is to use `implementation` instead of `compile` (even though mvnrepository.com still uses the legacy declarations in their snippets).

If you are completely new to Gradle, I suggest generating a sample application by running `gradle init` in an empty directory and going through the small wizard. When asked, select "application" as the project type, "Java" as the implementation language and "Groovy" as the DSL (unless you like to try out Kotlin of cause), and lastly either JUnit 4 or 5.